# Automatically deploy an Enterprise Application on AzureAD

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a React Application that uses Microsoft AD to authenticate users.

As a first step, and according to [Microsoft Documentation](https://Quickstart:%20Register%20an%20application%20with%20the%20Microsoft%20identity%20platform), we need to register the application with the Microsoft identity platform.

This is inline with [Microsoft Identity Platform Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview), in this diagram we can see that for ALL types of applications (SPA, Web App, etc), we always need to configure an application in AzureAD:

[image: Microsoft Identity Platform]

This process is "cumbersome", and i'm trying to remove it by having the application installed automatically.

Several third-parties do this, such as Zapier, SpecFlow, etc.
Basically, they have a process where:

- User logs in on Zapier
- User is redirected to Azure AD sign-in page
- User is authenticated and authorized
- AzureAD shows the Consent Page
- User consents
- Application is installed on user's AzureAD

[image]

I've been reading and searching in Microsoft's Documentation, and i cannot find a single document that shows or even mentions this type of flow.

BUT, i know that this is possible, as there are several third parties that are doing exactly this, as Zapier, for example.

**Can anyone point me in the right direction, there must exist some Microsoft document that explains how this process is done!**

Comment: this [mircosoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-react-spa-app) might help you to integrate azure ad in react app

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but we already have the authentication working. 
    Moreover, in the documentation you sent, the Application is also created Manually (see Step 2.1 Register the web API application) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-react-spa-app#step-2-register-your-react-spa-and-api.   My question is how to avoid this step, and have the Application deployed automatically after being authenticated, as Zapier and other third parties are doing!

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if this should be a comment, not an answer. I do not have enough SO reputation to write comments.

Zapier is published to the Azure Active Directory application gallery (1c76d9b0-0826-4b19-8706-29572657af1e). You can do this as well:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/v2-howto-app-gallery-listing

If an application already exists in the gallery, it does not need to be "registered" in the user's tenant, as the registration definition is defined in the gallery.

Once an app is in the gallery, users can use it only if their tenant's administrators allow this, per the settings on this page:

- Enterprise applications | User settings
  [https://entra.microsoft.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/StartboardApplicationsMenuBlade/~/UserSettings](https://entra.microsoft.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/StartboardApplicationsMenuBlade/%7E/UserSettings)

From the user's end, there are other governance controls that may impact the user's ability to use your app, but I think "register your app in the gallery" is probably what you're asking for.